# PHP curl returns code 200 even though the method throws an exception with code 400

Tags: php, php-curl

I've done an API and now I'm trying to make calls using the `curl` method and I'm trying to input bad data to get the errors and check all works well. But what I don't understand is why the `curl` call returns the code 200 when the input data is wrong and it throws an exception with code 400.

That's my `curl` call:

```
public function test() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://127.0.0.1/mysite/public/rest/createUser/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        "email" => "some.email",
        "address" => "elm street",
        "telephone" => "123123123",
    ]);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    var_dump($server_output);

}
```

In that case the email is not valid and the exception is thrown when calling the `createUser` method and shows.

```
{"error":"The email asd2123123 is invalid"}
```

And the code is 200 instead of 400

If I call the URL and I don't use the `curl` method it returns the code 400

Also I'm using Postman to make the calls and it returns the code 400 if I call directly to `createUser` and I put an invalid e-mail.

Comment: How do you call the URL without cURL ?

Comment: I use Postman for Chrome. I write the URL and in the body section I write the fields I want to set

Comment: Make sure the response doesn't get cached on the server/browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code that way :

```
public function test() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://127.0.0.1/mysite/public/rest/createUser/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        "email" => "some.email",
        "address" => "elm street",
        "telephone" => "123123123",
    ]);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode;
    var_dump($server_output);
}
```

Is the HTTP code still 200 ?

Comment: I get this two codes: `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` and `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Comment: Here is your answer. The code is well 400 you had code 200 because the page where you made the call of cURL won't appropriate the http code of the cURL call you see? Since cURL has well been executed your page will return 200, but as you can see the http code of the cURL is 400. Sorry for my bad english trying to explain the better possible.

Comment: Now I see it, and is there a way to return the correct code when something went wrong in the method called in cURL?

Comment: I suggest you to see the comment on the official [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-getinfo.php#41332)

Comment: Thanks for your help